# Unable to use WriteProfileInt() in a C++ windows application

Tags: .net, winforms, winapi, c++-cli

I am writing a C++ application, and I want to write an integer value to the INI file so that I can retain it back each time when i run the application.

But I am not able to use WriteProfileInt() API in my program, whenever I use this it gives me below error:-
'WriteProfileInt': identifier not found

However GetProfileInt() works fine, Can anyone please suggest me what should I do?
I am using Visual Studio 2013.

This is a sample code which I am using:-

```
public ref class main_form : public System::Windows::Forms::Form

{
public:

   int i2c_addr;
   int temp;

   main_form(void)
   {

      InitializeComponent();
   }

   void InitializeComponent(void)
   {
          WriteProfileInt(_T("device"),_T("i2c_address"),8);
          temp = GetProfileInt(_T("device"),_T("i2c_address"),0);
          this->i2c_addr = temp;
   }
}
```

But it gives me error for WriteProfileInt(_T("device"),_T("i2c_address"),8);

Please help me to proceed further on this.

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: public ref class main_form : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
 {
 public:
  int i2c_addr; 
  int temp;
        public: 
    Thread^ myThread;
  main_form(void)
  {
   InitializeComponent();
                }
         void InitializeComponent(void)
         {
           WriteProfileInt(_T("device"),_T("i2c_address"),5);
           temp = GetProfileInt(_T("device"),_T("i2c_address"),0);

Comment: you can update your original post with code.

Comment: Use the [edit] link to add code. Also, you've mistagged the question. You are not writing a C++ application, you are using the .NET Framework.

Comment: Also **do not use the `GetProfileString` or `WriteProfileString` functions!** Ever! They are provided only for compatibility with legacy 16-bit Windows applications. They write into the WIN.INI file, which no application should be modifying. Use `GetPrivateProfileString` and `WritePrivateProfileString` instead!

Comment: public ref class main_form : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
 {
 public:
  int i2c_addr; 
  int temp;
        public: 
    Thread^ myThread;
  main_form(void)
  {
   InitializeComponent();
                }
         void InitializeComponent(void)
         {
           WriteProfileInt(_T("device"),_T("i2c_address"),5);
           temp = GetProfileInt(_T("device"),_T("i2c_address"),0);
           this->set_i2c_addrs = temp;
          }
}
This is sample code which shows what I am doing in my code.

Answer (score 1):

On the API level you need to do something like this:

```
char bf[50];
sprintf(bf,"%d", my_int_value);
WriteProfileString("MyApp", "MySection", bf);  // will write to the registry
WritePrivateProfileString("C:\\myprog\\myprog.ini", "MySection", bf); // will write to the ini file
```

Hope this helps

Comment: No you wouldn't. Not unless you were a time-traveler. The `WriteProfileString` hasn't been used since the days of Windows 3. It writes into the WIN.INI file, which applications have no business modifying. The function you're looking for is `WritePrivateProfileString`. And you also wouldn't be using narrow strings. Windows has been fully Unicode for over a decade now, it's time to get with the program. To be fair, `WritePrivateProfileString` will match the encoding to the file, but you still should call the wide variant.

Comment: This function does NOT write to any profile .ini, it writes to the registry if this is the intention. If not, and the user wants to write to a file, then all these API functions come with the 'Private' versions. It is provided as a convenience function to simplify writing and reading from the registry.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is trying to set the clock back 21 years.  Back to Windows 3.11, the last version of Windows that still had the Win.ini configuration file.

That cannot work anymore.  The winapi still supports GetProfileInt() to emulate some common entries in a Win.ini file and keep legacy code running.  But WriteProfileInt() has been completely removed, there's no hope to pretend that the .ini file is still there and can possibly function correctly.  Backwards compatibility is pretty legendary in Windows but the buck stops somewhere.  You found out where.

System.ini and Win.ini have been functionally replaced by the registry.  You can use that instead, perhaps, the [RegistryKey class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) provides access to the registry.  In .NET, application settings are the recommended alternative to still keep configuration file-based.  Not convenient from C++/CLI however, the IDE doesn't have the settings designer like other languages have.  Keeping configuation in an XML file is in general a decent alternative, use the classes in the System.Xml namespace.